# Is there a method to execute next example group in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to do like this.

[Code]

```
describe "TestA" do

  it "1" do
    puts "in A-1"
  end

  it "2" do
    next() # REMARK HERE!!
           # I want to skip this example group from here.
    puts "in A-2"
  end

end

describe "TestB" do

  it "1" do
    puts "in B-1"
  end

end
```

[Stdout]

```
$ rspec
...
  TestA
    1
in A-1
  TestB
    1
in B-1
...
```

The sentence 'puts "in A-2"' is skipped by next() method. This is what i want.

Is there a method to execute next example group like above `next()` in RSpec?

Comment: You can put a `x` before `it` or `describe` (i.e. `xit`, `xdescribe`) to indicate that the example or group should be skipped temporarily, see [Pending and skipped examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples)

Comment: I think putting x or skip methods is not completed for 'real skipping' because these outputs some messages. I want to skip method to output no messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rspec provides some approaches to skip tests:

Call skip method inside a block

```
it "2" do
  skip
  puts "in A-2"
end
```

Set skip option to true

```
it "2", skip: true do
  puts "in A-2"
end
```

Add prefix `x` to `it`

```
xit "2" do
  puts "in A-2"
end
```

More information in [Official documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/skip-examples)

If you don't want to show skipped tests in an output when use `skip: true` and run rspec with `--tag "~skip"`

```
it "2", skip: true do
  puts "in A-2"
end
```

run rspec with `rspec --tag "~skip"`

or add `--tag ~skip` to .rspec file.